# Measuring a string vertically

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have a C# Winform application. In my form, I have a panel and in my panel, I have a label. The label gets created dynamically. I have the following code:

```
Label label1 = new Label();
label1.MaximumSize = new Size(400, 0);
label1.Location = new Point(posX, posY);
label1.Text = myText;
label1.AutoSize = true;
posY += 15;
```

Okay, everything is working. The text of the label automatically wraps after 400 pixels. The problem is, I need to create a second label, but how do I know what to set the the Location to? This new label need to be placed just below the first label and the first label might be 1 line long or 5 lines long. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not trying to be off topic here, but this is exactly the kind of thing WPF is great at.  If you have a choice, I would suggest you look into it.

Comment: Agreed, Unfortunately, not an option at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to place your label within **FlowLayoutPanel**, set the **FlowDirection** to Top Down.

Answer (score 1):

I would support [the answer which provided by Int3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944911/measuring-a-string-vertically/5945003#5945003), and another solution is to read the `Height` of label1 before set the `Top` of label2.

For example:

```
label2.Top = label1.Top + label1.Height + 10;
```

Comment: Wow I am going to try this. I don't know why I didn't think of such a simple answer like this lol

Answer (score 0):

A GridLayout with some rows might be a solution